# Use re.findall to extract id at the end of a URL

Tags: python, regex

```
sfdc_url= 'https://unify.my.salesforce.com/a0n82000006VlNaPPP'

sfdc_partnerid= re.findall(r'https://unify.my.salesforce.com/(.*?)?sr',sfdc_url)
```

I want sfdc_partnerid to return "a0n82000006VlNaPPP"

I keep getting an empty [] result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your url, the correct regex to work with would be:

```
sfdc_url= 'https://unify.my.salesforce.com/a0n82000006VlNaPPP'
sfdc_partnerid = re.findall(r'https://unify.my.salesforce.com/(.*)', sfdc_url)
print sfdc_partnerid
```

Check it also on https://eval.in/1078060

It's about quantifiers:
`*?` is a lazy quantifier, and matches as few characters as possible

`(.*?)` effectively means "match anything between zero and unlimited as few times as possible", which is empty.

Adding a `?` after that, means "zero or one of the previous match", so that:
`(.*?)?` effectively means "zero or one of nothing"

I'm not sure about the remaining `sr` in your original regex

Comment: thank you! what if I only wanted only alphanumeric characters after the last "/" in the url?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that would be `https://unify.my.salesforce.com/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) if you're on python3

e.g.

```
from urllib import urlparse
result = urlparse("https://unify.my.salesforce.com/a0n82000006VlNaPPP")
result.path
```